# Gradle error: Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes

Tags: java, android

To start off, this is the whole message:

> > Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception parsing classes
> >
> > Error:1 error; aborting
>
> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 1

This is what I have tried:
Restarting AS.
Restaring my computer.
Tried invaldiate caches and restart.
Rebuilt the project serveral times.

Earlier today I installed that latest java update, but it did not affect anything. After a couple of hours of coding, I added a jar file to my libs folder and wrote a class that used some of the classes from that library.

Now I can't seem to build the application at all anymore, even if comment out the class that uses the dependency.

Using Android Studio 2.0, Java 1.8.0_91-b14 and the library mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin

Edit:
I just tried removing the jar file, and now it builds just fine. So that's the thing causing the problem. Now how to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add the following line in your app's build.grade file

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Tried it, sadly it made no difference.

Comment: try to perform "Build" - "Clean project" and then "Rebuild Project"